# Why does wsl --install always yield Catastrophic Failure on my new Windows 11 Home 22H2 installation?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, virtual-machine, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to start using Ubuntu 22.04 inside my Windows 11 laptop using wsl. I have gotten this to work on my desktop. However, every time I try to run 'wsl --install' (or 'wsl --install -d Ubuntu-22.04'), it ends with 'Catastrophic failure'.

My laptop is a new Lenovo LOQ.

I'll happily provide any more system details that would be useful.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried running 'wsl --install' (or 'wsl --install -d Ubuntu-22.04') using powershell, command prompt, with and without 'run as administrator', as well as 'netsh winsock reset' & reboot.

I have also checked that VM is enabled in the BIOS.

I was expecting these to work, since online users found that they worked for them (from microsoft's support pages as well as reddit), but 'Catastrophic failure' was the result each time.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me; earlier I was facing the same issue.

```
wsl --shutdown
wsl --update  // asked admin permission
wsl --install // asked admin permission
```

Comment: Thank you. My elevated prompt did not help, but running the above as a normal user solved my issues.

Comment: `--shutdown` and `--update` are not valid options in my command prompt run as administrator.