Virtual Machine Platform (and possibly WSL also) not working with Podman
OS: Windows 10 Home (19045.4412)
I am trying to get Podman up and running to work with containers. Here is what it is showing me. I am focusing on the Virtual Machine Platform for now, and I will worry about the WSL errors after (or maybe it is all one related problem and they will get fixed together). The Virtual Machine Platform message links to this article in which it tells me to run the following: (as administrator)
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart

When I run it I get this:
C:\WINDOWS\system32>dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.19041.3636

Image Version: 10.0.19045.4412

Enabling feature(s)

And it just sits there indefinitely (I left it for around an hour before killing it)
Additionally, here is a screenshot of my Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features > Turn Windows features on and off menu, showing that both WSL and Virtual Machine Platform are enabled.
Also:
If the fact the WSL is not working is related to the Virtual Machine Platform issue, here is this: (If it isn't ignore this, I only want to worry about 1 thing at once)
C:\WINDOWS\system32>wsl --update
Installing: Windows Subsystem for Linux
Catastrophic failure

C:\WINDOWS\system32>wsl -l
Windows Subsystem for Linux has no installed distributions.
Distributions can be installed by visiting the Microsoft Store:
https://aka.ms/wslstore

I have Ubuntu 24.04 LTS installed via Microsoft Store, and I can run it by searching for it in the Start menu, but WSL does not recognize it.

WSL is no longer installed through Optional Windows Feature and instead installed exclusively through the Windows Store and the command “wsl --install”, but your WSL issues are absolutely connected to Virtual Machine Platform not actually being enabled. I would disable and uninstall all optional features, uninstall any WSL distributions, and uninstall WSL through the command then reboot your system and install everything. If that is unsuccessful I would do an in place upgrade to the same version of Windows you have installed because your inability to enable Virtual Machine Platform is a proble

Duplicate here: https://superuser.com/questions/1818227/why-does-wsl-install-always-yield-catastrophic-failure-on-my-new-windows-11-ho

Sorry for taking so long to reply. I got WSL working. How do I uninstall all of the optional features? Do I do it through the Turn Windows features on and off menu?
